# submitting multiple ans with singl submit button in mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql

i am trying to make a online quiz/survey using php and mysql!and im working with php for the very first time!
what im trying to do is take Questions and its multiple choices from my Db(quiz and table Questions with Qid, Qtext, Ans1..Ans4 as its 6 columns) and once the user is done with the quiz n presses the Submit button on last Question.. all the answers should be saved in Db(quiz and table answer with Aid, Ans, Qid as its columns)! i searched for related codes but couldnt understand any of them.
i would be grateful if somebody could help.
thanks.

Comment: did you find your answer?

Answer (score 0):

have inputs as an array in your view, like:

```
<input type="text" name="answer[]" />
<input type="text" name="answer[]" />
<input type="text" name="answer[]" />
```

and on submit ,

```
$answers = $_POST['answer'];

foreach($answers as $answer)
{
   ...
}
```

Comment: you mean ..using a loop .. we ll keep on adding all the answers in an array and on submit this array will be directed to DB.. right?

Comment: you need to handle every $answer.Or you can add this individual answer to an answerSheet. then save it.

Answer (score 0):

I can give you a short idea

```
<input type="text" name="answer[]" />
<input type="text" name="answer[]" />
<input type="text" name="answer[]" />
<input type="submit" name="submit">

//if you have query on another page that is in form action...there is no need of isset
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$ans=$_POST['answer']; //store in a variable, now this is array of your multiple answer

//iterate it by loop, best is foreach becouse it will continue iteration untill the element //found in array,

foreach($ans as $val)
{
mysqli_query($con, "insert into table_name set answer='$val'") or die("query failed");

} 
?>
```